# Transparent file compression apps for macOS

Tags: macos, file-compression, filesystems

I'm looking for app for macOS Sierra and above which would allow me to compress files transparently in the background to increase free space which works for macOS Sierra and above.

Basically I'm looking for alternatives for [Clusters app](http://latenitesoft.com/clusters/) which doesn't seems to work on Sierra.

> Clusters takes advantage of the file compression technology built into Mac OS X to help you regain space, keep your system tidy and launch your files faster. Clusters is a background and transparent file compressor: Mac OS and your apps will use compressed files without having to expand them first - they will just take less disk space and load faster.

Answer (score 2):

#### `afsctool`

There is a [`afsctool` tool](https://brkirch.wordpress.com/afsctool/) which allow to compress the folders in HFS+ file system.

> AFSC (Apple File System Compression) tool is an utility that can be used to apply HFS+ compression to file(s), decompress HFS+ compressed file(s), or get information about existing HFS+ compressed file(s). Mac OS 10.6 or later is required.

However it needs to be run manually from the command-line for specific folders, e.g. current dir:

```
afsctool -c .
```

or some specific folder:

```
afsctool -c ~/Downloads
```

To compress the files automatically, you can write some simple script to run it periodically.

Install AFSC tool via: `brew install afsctool`.

See also: [mirror at GitHub](https://github.com/RJVB/afsctool).

Related threads:

- [Creating an automated HFS+ compressed folder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/50525/22781).
- [How do I transparently compress a directory?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193893/22781)

Comment: 's answer is correct. I don't have reputation to comment on their answer, but I wanted to point out that there is a more up-to-date version of afsctool at https://github.com/RJVB/afsctool